# Using Win32, GetModuleBaseName() and GetModuleFileNameEx() fail with GetLastError() = 6 when using valid handle

Tags: winapi

First some simple code snippet:

```
m_hProcessHandle = ::OpenProcess((PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION), FALSE, m_dwProcessIdentifier);
if (NULL != m_hProcessHandle)
{
    if (FALSE != ::OpenProcessToken(m_hProcessHandle, (TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE), &m_hImpersonizationToken))
    {
        wchar_t wszFullExecutableFileName[MAX_PATH];
        if (0 == ::GetModuleBaseName(m_hProcessHandle, NULL, wszFullExecutableFileName, (sizeof(wszFullExecutableFileName)/sizeof(wchar_t))))
        {
            __DebugMessage(L"GetModuleBaseName() failed with GetLastError() = %d", ::GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            if (0 == ::GetModuleFileNameEx(m_hProcessHandle, NULL, wszFullExecutableFileName, (sizeof(wszFullExecutableFileName)/sizeof(wchar_t))))
            {
                __DebugMessage(L"GetModuleFileNameEx() failed with GetLastError() = %d", ::GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                m_strFullFileName = wszFullExecutableFileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [OpenProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) returns a valid handle as does the [OpenProcessToken()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken), but when I call the subsequent [GetModuleBaseName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulebasenamea) and [GetModuleFileNameEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa) functions, I get [GetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) = 6 (The handle is invalid). I am running that code as admin on Windows 7. What gives?

cheers,
GumbyTheBorg

Comment: Erm, wait, what are you actually doing with the process token?

Comment: For impersonation purposes within server. This is just a code snippet from a larger function.

Comment: Is it the `NULL` that’s the invalid handle (suggesting you first need to use `EnumProcessModules()` to find a handle to the module whose name you want to recover)?

Comment: I think @HansPassant means that you retrieve the process token into m_hImpersonizationToken, then don't use it. So `OpenProcessToken` has no effect.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is if I execute this code as Administrator, I don't encounter this error.

Answer (score 0):

You must run this program as administrator in order for it to work correctly.  I just tested it working and GetLastError() = 0 after each line, which means there were no problems.